# Allow Some Special Characters using Regex

Tags: php, regex

The following regex matches any **Unicode Letters** + **Unicode Numbers** + **Vowel Signs** + **Dot** + **Dash** + **Underscore** + **Space**

```
/^[\w\pN\pL\pM .-]+$/u
```

Works successfully.

I want to edit my regex so it accepts the following:

```
? ! ( ) % @ # , + - : newline
```

`-` represents negative sign.

My attempt doesn't work:

```
/^[\w\pN\pL\pM .-**?!()%@#,+-:\r**]+$/u
```

Here is my snippet with latest attempt:

```
if(preg_match('/^[\w\pN\pL\pM .-?!()%@#,+-:\r]+$/u', $_POST['txtarea_msg']))
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/^[\w\pN\pL\pM \?!\(\)%@#,\+\-:\n\r]+$/u` should do it.

Comment: For \n\r ... This is what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

`-` is a metacharacter in character classes, so you're saying:

blahblahblah all characters from `.` to `?` blahblahblah all characters from `+` to `:` blah blah

It needs to be escaped with a `\`:     `blahblah .\-? blahblah +\-: blahblah`

Comment: +1 for only escaping the character that NEEDS escaping in a character class.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can a capture not occur within a character class? I've never tried it, but assumed the parenthesis would need escaping as well.

Comment: You can capture the whole class, but not within a class. I don't know if there'd be any point in allowing in-class captures. By definition a character class is treated as a single character match location that MUST contain one of the in-class characters. Doing something like `[(ab)(cd)]` would just confuse things.if `a` matches and is captured, then `(cd)` could never occur. But you've used up a capture slot for cd, so what should go in there?

Comment: Makes sense. I didn't figure so. While I know you don't have to escape *everything* within character classes, I'm always leery of literal parenthesis. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score -1):

Some of these are regular expression characters, so you need to escape them:

```
/^[\w\pN\pL\pM .?!()%@#,+\-:\r]+$/u
```

Also note the difference between a newline (`\n`) and carriage return (`\r`).

Comment: Based on **Marc B**'s elaboration, I have removed the escaping of the parenthesis. I have left this answer as I believe, if nothing else, the note on the newline is relevant.